# \dt in psql exits shell

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have created a brand new instance and database which I am connecting to with psql. I have successfully ran a `CREATE TABLE` command and now I want to list the tables, so I write `\dt` and the shell exists with the message `exit status 0xc000005`.
[image]

I am unable to connect to the database with pgAdmin or another tool to check anything as it is hosted via a third party infrastructure platform with security restrictions that I cannot do anything about. Any suggestions to what might be wrong or how I can find out?

Comment: Does it work if you directly connect to it? Can you list the db's directly from the GUI? This is usually a memory access violation error in Windows which to me would point towards a issue with the installation or something deeper.

Comment: The people who run the database cannot be very security conscious, since they are running 14.5. Please, don't post images of text; it's impossible to copy and paste from. Anyway, 0xc0000005 is Windows' code for a segmentation violation. I suspect that you have a mix of PostgreSQL software from different sources installed, which are not compatible with each other. Please edit the question and tell us your operating system and the list of all PostgreSQL software installed. As text, not as an image!